# A problem with installing ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with installing ROS on my Ubuntu 11.04 .. an error have occurred at 90% of the installation .. It was a problem with the SSH server !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45447/a-problem-with-installing-ros/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-09**:
Please post more information otherwise it's impossible to help you. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-09**:
This is the error I have :

SSH error: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer

and I have searched for a solution and I have found this : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howot-install-ubuntu-linux-ssh-server.html

but I can't change the port number from 22 to 215 as mentioned in the link

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-14**:
What's the command you are running?

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-23**:
now,i have updated my version from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10
and when writing the command:  sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
I got this :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to  locate package ros-electric-desktop-full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree you need more information.  But in regards to SSH, could this be your issue?

http://answers.ros.org/question/40560/rosinstall-hack-to-use-http-instead-of-git/

---

Originally posted by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) with karma: 506 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0